# Implementing Entity and Component in a game engine

Tags: c#, game, design-patterns, entity-component-system

I'm currently creating a game engine for my personal project.
And I'm currently implementing Entity and Component System.

#### Classes and Interfaces Definitions

Here the classes and interfaces that involved to this problem:

- `Entity`: abstract class for any entity in the game, it does not implement any interface or class. It has `Children` mechanism, so an `Entity` can add another `Entity` as it child and able to remove it any time, it can also contains multiple `Component`.
- `Component`: abstract class for any component in the game. The `Component` is used to add, remove and / or modify the behavior or ability of an `Entity`. I use this to aid C# limitation that a class cannot inherit multiple classes at a time. `Entity` can contains multiple `Component`, however, it cannot contains multiple `Component` with same type at the same time.
- `Scene`: a class that represent a "Screen" or "State" in the game. `Scene` can contains multiple `Entity` objects and responsible for render the `Entity` that implement `IRenderable` as well as updating `Entity` that implement `IUpdatable` and `IInputable`
- `IRenderable`: Represent an object that can be rendered and displayed on the screen.
- `IUpdatable`: Represent an object that can be updated each frame in the game.
- `IInputable`: Represent an object that able to receive player input.

#### The Codes

So here the simplified codes:

Entity:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    private List<Component> _components = new List<Component>();
    private List<Entity> _children = new List<Entity>();

    public void AddChild(Entity child)
    {
        _children.Add(child);
    }

    public void RemoveChild(Entity child)
    {
        _children.Remove(child);
    }

    public Entity[] GetChildren()
    {
        return _children.ToArray();
    }

    public void AddComponent<T>()
        where T : Component
    {
        if (_components.Find((c) => c is T) != null)
            return; // each entity can only contains one type of component at the same time

        var component = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        component.Owner = this;
        _components.Add(component);
    }

    public void RemoveComponent<T>()
        where T : Component
    {
        var component = _components.Find((c) => c is T);
        if (component == null)
            return;

        component.Owner = null;
        _components.Remove(component);
    }

    public Component[] GetComponents()
    {
        return _components.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Component:

```
public abstract class Component
{
    public Entity Owner { get; protected internal set; }
}
```

Scene:

```
public class Scene : IRenderable, IUpdatable, IInputable
{
    private List<Entity> _entities = new List<Entity>();

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }

    public void Add(Entity entity)
    {
        _entities.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Remove(Entity entity)
    {
        _entities.Remove(entity);
    }

    // Render, Update and Input function in the Scene will automatically called at the game loop by game window
    public void Render(RenderTarget target, RenderStates states)
    {
        if (Visible)
        {
            foreach (var entity in _entities)
            {
                if (entity is IRenderable)
                    ((IRenderable)entity).Render(target, states);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Update(double delta)
    {
        if (Enabled)
        {
            foreach (var entity in _entities)
            {
                if (entity is IUpdatable)
                    ((IUpdatable)entity).Update(delta);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Input(InputEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Enabled)
        {
            foreach (var entity in _entities)
            {
                if (entity is IInputable)
                    ((IInputable)entity).Input(e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The Interfaces:

```
public interface IRenderable
{
    bool Visible { get; set; }
    void Render(RenderTarget target, RenderStates states);
}

public interface IUpdatable
{
    bool Enabled { get; set; }
    void Update(double delta);
}

public interface IInputable
{
    bool Enabled { get; set; }
    void Input(InputEventArgs e);
}
```

#### Questions

1. Does any class / interface violates or lacking it's capability and / or functionality from it's name? for example, `IRenderable` enforce the class that implement it to implement `Visible` property, which mean all "Renderable" object should have "Visible" state, is such design correct?
2. At the shown code above, the `Scene` is not responsible to check the `Entity` children and it's components, and it also possible to add another `Entity` as a child while implementing interface that not implemented by it's parent. Consider following example:

   ```
   public class CustomEntity : Entity
   {
       // Some codes here...
   }

   public class Sprite : Entity, IRenderable
   {
       public bool Visible { get; set; }

       // ...

       public void Render(RenderTarget target, RenderStates states)
       {
           // If the sprite is not visible, it should not render itself and ignore the children
           if (!Visible)
               return;

           // Render the sprite here...

           // Since scene does not check the Entity children, 
           // We need to render the child and components in case they implement IRenderable
           foreach (var child in GetChildren())
           {
               if (child is IRenderable) 
               {
                   if (((IRenderable)child).Visible)
                       ((IRenderable)child).Render(target, states);
               }
           }

           foreach (var component in GetComponents())
           {
               if (component is IRenderable) 
               {
                   if (((IRenderable)component).Visible)
                       ((IRenderable)component).Render(target, states);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   the `CustomEntity` does not implement `IRenderable` interface, however, it is possible to do something like this:

   ```
   var myEntity = new CustomEntity();
   var mySprite = new Sprite();

   myEntity.AddChild(mySprite);
   ```

   and of course `mySprite` won't be rendered when `myEntity` is added to the `Scene`, the same thing applies to the `Component`. Is this correct behavior? or should `Scene` handle those stuffs?

That's all for now, in case you find something weird with the design, I'm open for suggestion. I'll update the question if I've got something more to ask.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Basically, don't update your code in the question based on advice, as it invalidates people's answers. If your code doesn't represent your actual code, we'd normally see that as off-topic, because people will give advice on the code your present, and if it doesn't MATCH the code you actually have, you might get useless advice. Something to remember.

Answer (score 3):

Some issues:

Your type casting is not the most readable. Also, if you use the casted object more than once, it may be less inefficient.

Instead of:

```
if(object is Type)
     ((Type)object).DoSomething();
```

Use:

```
var casted = object as Type;
if (casted != null) {
    casted.DoSomething();
}
```

This way, you do not need to cast the object every time it is used, so it may be faster, and it is more readable.

Also, for your components, it may be faster to use a `Dictionary<Type, Component>`, as it does not need to iterate through every key, so instead of:

```
if (_components.Find((c) => c is T) != null)
     return;
```

You should use:

```
if (_components.ContainsKey(typeof(T))) {
    return;
}
```

It is also a bad practice to exclude braces from `if` statements, as it may confuse some if there are multiple statements, all indented.

For example, you may write:

```
if (condition)
    DoSomething();
    DoSomethingElse();
```

At first, it may look perfectly normal, especially if you are doing a quick read-through. (Of course, using an auto-indenter solves the problem, but the code may still be hard to read for some.)

Furthermore, in this method:

```
public Entity[] GetChildren()
{
    return _children.ToArray();
}
```

you are converting a `List` to an `Array`. Since `List` uses an `Array` internally, it is not expensive, but unless you have a good reason to keep it, it's better to leave it in list form. The same applies to `GetComponents`.

To answer your questions:
2. This should be good object-oriented code. The object-specific methods are defined on each object, and the `Scene`, which has a role of rendering the items, should be the one calling the `Render` method.

If it is intended for the children of `CustomEEntity` to be visible, it will be best to implement the `Render` method and `Visible` property in the `CustomEntity`.

On the other hand, if `CustomEntity` is not related to rendering, it should not have an `IRenderable` child at all. In this case, you may want to check the interfaces implemented by each child and component before adding, and make sure the object implements the interfaces as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I changed type casting code and use Dictionary to store the components. About the braces, I stripped the braces from original codes for simplicity sake, I'll edit the question.  

Anyway, so the `Scene` is the one that should calling the `Render` method of an `Entity` *and it's children*?

Comment: The method in the `Entity` should render its children, especially especially since it may be nested. The `Render` method should do everything the `Entity` needs to render fully, but it should always be called by the renderer.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, and I saw your edited answer
everything seems to be clear now!

Comment: If you want to prevent the `IRenderable` from being added, the easiest way is probably to have a method that takes an `Entity parent`, and `Entity child`, then in the function do something like: `if (!parent is <interface> && child is <interface>) {throw new <yourexception>("<interface>")}`, where `<yourexception>` prints something like `"Parent does not support {0}", interface`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I need one more thing to clarify: how about the `Component`s? the main purpose of  `Component` is to add, remove as well as modify an Entity behavior. for example: I need to add `IUpdatable` and `IRenderable` `Component` to an `Entity` while the `Entity` itself doesn't implement those interfaces. In such case, the `Component` need to be updated (and rendered) on each frame while the `Entity` itself is not (It's sounds make sense for me). What should I do in such case? is `Component` should apply same rule as the Child? or let the `Scene` handle the `Component` stuffs?